# What is the word for the feeling when the piano key catches at the bottom of a press. The word for when the jack slips

Tags: piano, terminology, instruments

I apologize I’m not a musician, I’m writing poetry and I heard someone talk about that click a little over 3/4s of the way down a piano key, when the jack catches and the hammer is launched. It sounded like declanshe. But I can’t find the actual spelling or precise definition anywhere. Does anyone know? Id really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

The term you're looking for is ***let-off***. This is the highest point at which the jack still supports the hammer. There is also the ***drop***, which is the point at which the repetition level (through which the jack slips) supports the hammer.

These are discussed in more detail at [88keys](https://88keys.sg/technical-specifications-of-the-grand-piano-action/).

A detailed action diagram can be found at [ConcertPitchPiano](https://www.concertpitchpiano.com/GrandActionModel.html).

Comment: And to round out this answer, the French word the asker heard is certainly [déclenche](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9clenche).